# Apache httpclient 4.x 302 redirects with keepalive off?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've been trying to make an HTTP GET request to a server which returns a 302 with a redirect path using HttpClient 4.4.1 (GA). I'm having some issues making it work seamlessly when not using keepalive.

Here is my code:

```
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest");
    Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION,
            "close");
    ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    headers.add(header);
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

    try{    
        entity = response.getEntity();  
            if (entity != null) {
                long len = entity.getContentLength();
                if (len != -1 && len < 2048) {
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                } 
                else {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    try {
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        IOUtils.copy(instream, writer, "UTF-8");
                        responseBody = writer.toString();
                    } finally {
                        instream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    finally{
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        response.close();
        client.close();
    }
```

Pretty straightforward.

When getting the GET request, the server responds with

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
    Content-Length: 0
    Location: http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=250849653588053716653279720260905006780
    Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2015 19:18:42 GMT
```

Cool, now we know where to go. The problem is, the httpclient then complains with the error:

```
    Apr 08, 2015 2:39:29 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
    INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354:         The target server failed to respond
    Apr 08, 2015 2:39:29 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
    INFO: Retrying request to /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354
```

True to its word, it then retries to recover from the IOException and sends another request with the redirect URL, in the same connection!

```
    GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=250849653588053716653279720260905006780 HTTP/1.1
    Connection: close
    Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.7.0_55)
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Now, since we I specified "Connection: close" as the header since the beginning, the server catches on by the this point and closes the socket on its side. My client then gets a RST signal. The request is resent again for the redirected Url, and things work this time.

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to stop the client from sending the redirect request in the same connection. I managed to "solve" this by disabling redirects after the first request with `disableRedirectHandling()` on the CloseableHttpClient object and then processing the 302 response myself in a separate connection. If I use keepAlive to deal with this problem, things also work fine, although then I have to timeout the client socket with a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` strategy after I'm done.

Is there a way the HttpClient 4.4.1 can handle the processing of 302 redirects in separate requests automatically?

EDIT: Posting the complete communication for the GET request as asked.

```
    GET /video/Manifest HTTP/1.1
    Connection: close
    Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.7.0_55)
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

    HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
    Content-Length: 0
    Location: http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=250849653588053716653279720260905006780
    Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 14:36:42 GMT

    GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=250849653588053716653279720260905006780 HTTP/1.1
    Connection: close
    Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java 1.5 minimum; Java/1.7.0_55)
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

I then get the RST signal from the server.

Header Wire + context logging.

```
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:657 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:667 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:668 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:679 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:681 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:683 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:686 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 127.0.0.1:46323<->10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:686 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /video/Manifest HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:686 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:687 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:688 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /video/Manifest HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:688 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: close
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:688 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:688 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.7.0_55)
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:688 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:700 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:700 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:701 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Location: http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:701 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 19:57:25 GMT
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:707 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:707 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354] can be kept alive indefinitely
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:707 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:709 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirect requested to location 'http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850'
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:713 EDT [DEBUG] RedirectExec - Redirecting to 'http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850' via /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:714 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:714 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:714 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:715 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:715 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850 HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:715 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:716 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:716 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850 HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:716 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: close
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:716 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:716 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.7.0_55)
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:717 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:717 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [INFO] RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354: The target server failed to respond
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:718 EDT [DEBUG] RetryExec - The target server failed to respond <org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond>org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at WorkingNonKeepAliveUseCase.requestWithoutKeepAlive(WorkingNonKeepAliveUseCase.java:109)
        at Runner.main(Runner.java:13)

    2015/04/08 15:57:25:720 EDT [INFO] RetryExec - Retrying request to /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:720 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:720 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:720 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 127.0.0.1:40753<->10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850 HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:721 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:722 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> GET /video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850 HTTP/1.1
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:722 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: close
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:722 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: 10.104.107.22:1354
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:722 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.7.0_55)
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:722 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:792 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:792 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Length: 17090
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:792 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Pragma: no-cache
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:793 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:793 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:793 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 19:57:25 GMT
    2015/04/08 15:57:25:794 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:795 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 1][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354] can be kept alive indefinitely
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:796 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 1][route: /127.0.0.1->{}->http://10.104.107.22:1354][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:796 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:796 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:797 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
    2015/04/08 15:57:26:797 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete wire / context log?

Comment: Done. Let me know if that's sufficient.

Comment: Any chance you could post the log generated by HttpClient as described here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/logging.html?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't know the HttpClient came with such debugging capabilities. I already learned something new! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part

```
2015/04/08 15:57:25:700 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
2015/04/08 15:57:25:700 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
2015/04/08 15:57:25:701 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Location: http://10.104.107.22:1354/video/Manifest?sessionID=162729772390321694625639849465722594850
2015/04/08 15:57:25:701 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 19:57:25 GMT
```

The redirect response sent back by the server does not contain any clues that the server intends to close the connection afterwards. HttpClient dutifully returns the connection back to the pool alive and gets it back to handle the redirect leading to an I/O error.

Is there really a good reason to completely disable connection persistence? I think you might be better off letting HttpClient re-use connections for the same session and then immediately evicting all persistent connections from the connection pool once the session is over.

From Oleg Kalnichevski in the follow-up comments.

> HttpClient expects the opposite endpoint to explicitly state its intent and send 'Connection: close' if it intends to drop the connection.

This fixed my problem.

Comment: Well, the use case was to create a sampler that could have the ability to request both using keep_alive or non keep_alive, based on user preference. While I "could" use persistence to deal with retry issue, I'm confused to as why the HttpClient isn't smart enough to see that I set the "Connection:close" header and not attempt to shove any more requests in the same connection. From the RFC http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-44 `If either the client or the server sends the close token in the
   Connection header, that request becomes the last one for the
   connection.`

Comment: To add to the weirdness of it all, our old implementation using HttpClient 4.2.6 does not exhibit this behaviour. The retry is done automatically for the 302 redirect on a separate connection. Maybe something changed/broke between libraries?

Comment: It is perfectly legal and permissible for both endpoints to drop connection at _any_ point without _any_ handshaking. The whole point of using 'Connection: close' is to negotiate a graceful connection termination by both endpoints. The spec also says "If the server chooses to close the connection immediately after sending the response, it SHOULD send a Connection header including the connection-token close." HttpClient expects the opposite endpoint to explicitly state its intent and send 'Connection: close' if it intends to drop the connection.

Comment: Yes, I read that part as well. I already spoke to the developers of the server and the header will be added to the response. I hope this will give the httpclient the information it needs to stop it from queuing up the retry request on the same connection. I still think that if the httpclient is given the "Connection : close" header it should be intelligent enough to avoid reusing the connection. Sending more requests on the same connection clearly violates the RFC.

Comment: Your comment regarding "HttpClient expects the opposite endpoint to explicitly state its intent and send 'Connection: close' if it intends to drop the connection." was indeed the solution. Now that the server sends the header, the automatic retry is done on a separate connection. The client apparently has no say on what is done on its end of the connection for an automatic redirect. If we want to close, but the server says Keep-Alive, then it will be kept alive. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Alan Silva Nonetheless, please raise a change request / bug report in ASF JIRA for this issue.